# Approximated square root in java

Tags: java, methods

The program I'm writing needs to read a double entered by the user, then read the input of a guess of what would be the square root of the first one, and then use the babylonian method to find out what is the square root of the first number(basically it uses the last guess to make a new one and then repeat this until find out what is the right one) `nextGuess + (lastGuess + (num / lastGuess))/2`

The problem is that not just I can't input a double in any part of the code without generating an error (will be shown below), as well as I can't make the equation work for some reason, even though I already checked the numbers one million times.

Here is the code of the 2 classes I'm using:
Main Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please input a number:");
  double num = in.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Input your guess for square root of the number:");
  double lastGuess = in.nextInt();
    Sqrtclass met = new Sqrtclass();
    double e = 0.001;
    met.set_guess(num, lastGuess);
      for (int i=1; i<=1000; i=i+1){
  if(met.nextGuess - lastGuess >= e){
    System.out.println("The number " + met.nextGuess + " couldn't be precise enough. Please input this number in the box below.");
    lastGuess = in.nextInt();
  }
  else if(met.nextGuess - lastGuess <= e){
  System.out.println("The square root of " + num + " is " + met.nextGuess);
  i = 1001;
  break;
  }   
    }
  }
}
```

The second class or Sqrtclass.java:

```
class Sqrtclass{
  static double nextGuess;
  public static double set_guess(double lastGuess, double num){
    nextGuess = (lastGuess + num / lastGuess)/2;
    return nextGuess;
   }
  }
```

And this is the error I said it shows up when I input a number with decimals during the execution of the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

What exactly was my mistake here? I can't think of much things that I haven't tried yet.

Comment: *"I can't think of much things that I haven't tried yet."* - You could have tried using a debugger.  You could also could have fixed the indentation .... which would have made the problem easier for you (and others) to spot.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problems. There were two basically.

The first were when I called the doubles from other classes. I was using `met.set_guess(num, lastGuess);` in the main class and in the second class I've put `public static double set_guess(double lastGuess, double num)`. This is, I was switching the orders of the doubles.

The second was also in the main class, what happened is that I'd put the for loop before the constructor calling the public static double. What I mean is:

It was like this:

```
    met.set_guess(num, lastGuess);
      for (int i=1; i<=1000; i=i+1){
```

When it should be like this:

```
      for (int i=1; i<=1000; i=i+1){
    met.set_guess(num, lastGuess);
```

Now the program is working perfectly. Thanks for everyone that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `nextInt()`, which requires a whole number. Try `.nextDouble()`.

Comment: I saw that a little after posting the question! Even though it is helpful, I keep having the same problem. Can you think of anything else I may have done to leave it wrong like that?